# Expected Shortfall vs VaR

Tags: quantiles, conditional-expectation, risk

I have a question about how to compute the Expected Shortfall practically. I know from the theory that the ES is the conditional Expectation of the Loss distribution (conditional on the VaR) and that it is intrinsically greater than the VaR:

> ES_α = E[L|L > VaR_α]

[image]

Following this formula I have calculated the VaR in R using `quantile(loss, probs=0.999)` function on my loss distribution. Then I have filtered the loss distribution observations greater than the VaR, `filter(loss > VaR)`, and applied on this filtered loss distribution the expectation formula using `sum(x*probability(x))`.

However it turns out that the VaR is greater than the ES. How is it possible? Having the Loss distribution how should I calculate VaR and ES? Did I do it wrong?

Comment: VaR is the $\alpha$ quantile value, CVaR is the mean of all the values up to the $\alpha$ quantile, so CVaR will be $\leq$ VaR (if we are talking about the lower tail).

Comment: With CVaR you mean ES? Anyway if I compute the "mean of all the values up to the α quantile" the ES > VaR, because it doesn't consider the relative frequencies of the loss observations, something that the expected value formula instead considers. So, shouldn't the "mean of all the values up to the α quantile" be instead weighted to the relative frequencies?

Comment: Also worth noting: in your graph, the ES is **not** the colored area (which is simply equal to $1-a$), as your arrow would indicate. The ES will be a value on the x-axis, in this case to the right of VaR.

Comment: Do you have a parametric distribution fit or just samples? If only samples see Richard Hardy answer below; if a parametric distribution fit I recommend a plugin estimator -- it's more stable especially for very high alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulating from a standard normal distribution as your chart suggests, you should get something like this

```
set.seed(2022)
loss <- rnorm(10^6)
VaR <- quantile(loss, probs=0.999)
VaR  # about qnorm(0.999) i.e. 3.090232
#    99.9% 
# 3.090315
mean(loss[loss >= VaR]) # about dnorm(qnorm(0.999))/(1-0.999) i.e. 3.36709
# 3.36505
```

It is not totally clear to me what the probabilities are in `sum(x*probability(x))` but assuming the `x` are losses greater than `VaR` then what you want is the conditional expectation `sum(x*probability(x))/sum(probability(x))`

Comment: Why should expected shortfall approximately equal `dnorm(qnorm(0.999))/(1-0.999)`?

Comment: @RichardHardy You can do the integration, but essentially this is the mean of a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating ES as `sum(x*probability(x))`, make sure to adjust the probabilities so that they sum up to one. If you have filtered the data to only keep losses greater than VaR, simply take their empirical mean by `mean(...)`.